# Django - Modifying Multiple Records Indirectly

Tags: python, django

In my project I need a form in which I can edit multiple employee records at once. However, due to the nature of the problem, the option that needs to be on the form does not directly correspond to a model field. The model field is in fact an integer, that depending on the selection should be incremented, set to zero, or kept the same.

I suspect this is a case where formsets could be useful but currently I am unsure. Any advice or pointers towards what a solution would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You might be able to do this with [prefixes for forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms).

Comment: is the number of possible selection limited? i.e. one selection causes increment, one causes zero, and one causes staying the same?

Comment: "I suspect this is a case where formsets could be useful but currently I am unsure."

Try and see?

Comment: @CameronTaylor Yes that is correct.

Comment: @marcusshep I have tried and can see how to edit multiple records using a modelformset. However I cannot find any documentation or examples in regards to creating a custom form field that would indirectly update a model field depending on the selection.